# UnitConvert having trouble multiplying Boltzmann's Constant with Fahrenheit?

Tags: units

```
T:=70 Quantity["DegreesFahrenheit"]
kb:=Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"]
UnitConvert[kb UnitConvert[T, "Kelvins"], "Electronvolts"] // N
```

Returns 0.0253575 eV while

```
T:=70 Quantity["DegreesFahrenheit"]
kb:=Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"]
UnitConvert[kb T, "Electronvolts"] // N
```

Returns 0.00335119 eV. Shouldn't the two be equivalent? I was wondering why there is a discrepancy.

Comment: But why are you using non-absolute temperature units with Boltzmann's constant?

Comment: I was getting lazy when estimating room temperature (grew up using Fahrenheit so I have no sense of what room temperature is in C) . Does UnitConvert not handle this automatically?

Comment: Read the [Temperature Units Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TemperatureUnits.html) and pay attention to this quote: "When working with absolute temperatures, it is imperative to first standardize the units, to allow for proper unit conversions."  `UnitConvert[kb UnitConvert@T, "Electronvolts"] // N` will work.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much!